# ¿Como quitar el setError despues de colocar la fecha con datePicker?

Tags: java, android-studio

Buenas noches amigos de la programación,tengo una validación en el campo fecha con `EditText`el cual lo tengo con `DatePicker`, pero el detalle que tengo cuando ya agrego la fecha el `setError` no se quita se mantiene ahí aun ya teniendo datos en el campo.

**validación de campo fecha**

```
 String fechaRegistro= texfechaingreso.getText().toString();
if (fechaRegistro.isEmpty()){
        texfechaingreso.setError("Favor de llenar el campo fecha de ingreso");
        retorno = false;
    } else{
       texfechaingreso.setError(null);
      }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado añadiendo un "else" y poniendo: texfechaingreso.setError(null); aunque no recuerdo si es: texfechaingreso.setError("");

Comment: @FranCámara ya intente de esa manera y no me funciono

Answer (score 0):

puedes ver esta pregunta de stackoverflow:

[Solución en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640772/edittext-seterror-message-does-not-clear-after-input)

En ella se ve que la solución es poner el valor "null" al "setError", de esta forma:
texfechaingreso.setError(null);

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar

```
editText.setError(null);
```

pero puedes agregar tambien el llamado para limpiar el foto del `EditTExt`

```
editText.setError(null);
editText.clearFocus();
```

Comment: ya lo intente de esa forma pero como es null no me muestra la validación que ese campo esta vacio.

Comment: Quieres decir que cuando ingresas un texto se mantiene?

Comment: No con la opcion null si presiono el botón registrar ya no me aparece nada para que el usuario sepa que ahí falta agregar datos

Comment: Lo tengo ya editado la pregunta es así como  antes lo tenia pero no me funciona ya aun cuando tiene agregado la fecha el icono rojo no se quita, no se porque el else no lo toma en cuenta.